# Adding complex default value with Python's argparse

Tags: python

I am using `argparse` to parse console input. For one of my input options, I'd like to add a default option that depends on other options:

```
parser.add_argument('--job_name')
parser.add_argument('--user_name',
                    default='guest')
```

I'd like the user to be able to define a `job_name`, but if the user does not define one, I'd like the `job_name` to be `user_name + datetime.date.today()`, (e.g. `'guest2016-10-23'`).

Is it possible to do this within `argparse`? Perhaps by giving a `lambda`...?

Comment: You could just have the help provided by the argparser instance say that, and then in the function that actually do the work generate your desired default value if none was supplied.  Keep the implementation decoupled from argparser so both things can be reused independently from each other.

Comment: Yeah. I figured I could use this. I was just wondering if `argparse` supplied a way to do it. Thanks! : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is impossible, because you can't use "args.user_name" before it is initialized.
But you can do this:

```
import argparse
import datetime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--job_name', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--user_name', default='guest')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.job_name is None:
    args.job_name = args.user_name + str(datetime.date.today())
```